# Good practice to avoid duplicate records

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have a application where users can add update and delete a record, I wanted to know the best ways to avoid duplicate records. In this application to avoid duplicate records i created a index on the table, is it a good practice or there are others?

Comment: will you explain some more thing like your fields and table.And what kind of duplication you want to avoid.

Comment: I agree with @Sandesh - what do youy want to avoid? Do you want to block user inserting duplicate data, or do you want to keep multiple rows with same data? would you like an error to be displayed, or just continue as if nothing is wrong?

Comment: How does duplicate records appear in the system? Are users submitting data more than once? Are multiple users entering the same data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`UNIQUE` constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190024.aspx) on columns or on a set of columns that you don't want to be duplicated; see also http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp.

Here is an example for both a single-column and a multi-column unique constraint:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [Person]
(
    …
    [SSN] VARCHAR(…) UNIQUE,  -- only works for single-column UNIQUE constraint
    …
    [Name] NVARCHAR(…),
    [DateOfBirth] DATE,
    …
    UNIQUE ([Name], [DateOfBirth])  -- works for any number of columns
)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this.  If you have a unique index on a field and you try to insert a duplicate value SQL Server with throw an error.  My preferred way is to test for existence before the insert by using

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM MyTable WHERE MyField = @ValueToBeInserted)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MyTable (Field1, Field2) Values (@Value1, @Value2)
END
```

You can also return a value to let you know if the `INSERT` took place using an `ELSE` on the above code.

If you choose to index a field you can set `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` to simply ignore any duplicate inserts. If you were inserting multiple rows any duplicates would be ignored and the non duplicates would continue to be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

An id for a table is almost compulsory according to me. To avoid duplicates when inserting a row, you can simply use :

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Table(id, name) VALUES (null, "blah")
```

This works in MySQL, i'm not sure about SQL Server.

Comment: AFAIK, this exact syntax does not exist in SQL Server's dialect of SQL (T-SQL). Use [`MERGE … WHEN NOT MATCHED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-ch/library/bb510625.aspx) instead.